# Android circular array generation issue

Tags: android, arrays

I have tried to write a method to generate an array using a base pattern in this way:
the method uses a base pattern and a `X` value, and must create a result array of size X loading `base` in circular way

if I have

```
String base[] = "A", "B", "C"
```

if `x=4` the result should be

```
res[] = "A", "B", "C"
```

if `x=11`

```
"A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B"
```

and so on

My code is this

```
public static String[] circ(Context c, int size){
            String[] base = {c.getResources().getString(R.string.ChannelA), c.getResources().getString(R.string.ChannelB), c.getResources().getString(R.string.ChannelC)};
            String res[];
            if(size>base.length){
                int deltaSize=size-base.length;
                int listSize=base.length+deltaSize;
                res=new String[listSize];
                for(int i=0; i<listSize; i++){
                    if(i<base.length){
                        res[i]=base[i];
                    }
                    else{
                        res[i]=base[i-base.length];
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                res=base;
            }
            return res;
        }
```

but doesn't work and I cannot find what is wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: BEsides `getSting <> getString`, i'd change the line  `res[i]=base[i-base.length]` to `res[i]=base[i % base.length]`, in fact with this module operator you can shrink the for-loop to `for(int i=0; i<listSize; i++) res[i]=base[i % base.length];`and it would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the modulo operation, it makes the code easier:

```
public static String[] circ(Context c, int size){
    String[] base = /.../
    String res[];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        res[i] = base[i % base.length];
    }

    return res;
}
```